# Problem when querying in SQLite with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am practicing with a SQLite database in Kotlin and I want to consult information once registered.

The problem is that when I press the button to consult, I get the message that I put in the Toast and not the one that I register.

```
class QLiteOpenHelper(context: Context, name: String, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("create table articulos(codigo int primary key, descripcion text,precio real)")
    }
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    }
}


 bt_registrar.setOnClickListener {
//Llamr a la base de datos
            val admin = QLiteOpenHelper(this, "Administracion", null, 1)
            val bd = admin.writableDatabase
            //Llamamos los datos
            val registro = ContentValues()
            registro.put("Codigo", et_codigo.text.toString())
            registro.put("Descripcion", et_name.text.toString())
            registro.put("Articulo", et_precio.text.toString())
            //Insertar los datos en la tabla articulos
            bd.insert("artculos", null, registro)
            bd.close()
            et_codigo.setText("")
            et_name.setText("")
            et_precio.setText("")
            Toast.makeText(this, "Los datos se han cargado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


bt_producto_codigo.setOnClickListener {

            val codigo = et_codigo.text.toString().toInt()

            val admin = QLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1)
            val bd = admin.writableDatabase
            val fila = bd.rawQuery("select descripcion,precio from articulos where codigo=$codigo", null)
            if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
                et_name.setText(fila.getString(0))
                et_precio.setText(fila.getString(1))
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "No existe un artículo con dicho código",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            bd.close()
            
        }
```

Comment: *when I press the button to consult....* which part of your code is this? Edit your question and clarify.

Comment: when I press the button (bt_producto_codigo.setOnClickListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert didn't pass

```
registro.put("Codigo", et_codigo.text.toString())
```

"Codigo" needs to be same like in the

```
db.execSQL("create table articulos(codigo int primary key, descripcion text,precio real)")
```

match cases and type for all the fields
best practice would be to use constants for keys. for example:

```
const val ARTICULOS_KEY ="articulos"
const val CODIGO_KEY ="codigo"    
...
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $ARTICULOS_KEY($CODIGO_KEY INT PRIMART....)
...
registro.put(CODIGO_KEY, et_codigo.text.toString().toInt())
```